# Sinatra Web Admin (like Django Admin)

Tags: ruby, django, django-admin, sinatra

Is there a way to get a Django Admin style web-admin for Sinatra?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not used it, but this showed up pretty quickly via Google: http://www.padrinorb.com/

Answer (score 1):

Another option is Sinatra Admin: https://github.com/ratnakarrao-nyros/sinatra-admin

Comment: @kittyminky2 no, I just heard about it